# WPF MVVM mahapps can't close Custom Dialog

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog

Well, I've been following the mahapps metro demo application and I saw the Custom Dialog via MVVM and yeah, its working perfectly but then again I've been using a UserControl as the content of the Custom Dialog that's being shown.

```
private async void OpenUserAccountDialog()
        {
            CustomDialog = new CustomDialog() { Content = new CreateUserDialog() };
            await DialogCoordinator.ShowMetroDialogAsync(this, CustomDialog);
        }
```

The above code works perfectly.
Accessing the MainViewModel is no problem, I can do something like:

```
public ActionCommand CloseDialogCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new ActionCommand(p => CloseDialog());
            }
        }
```

Then call it from my XAML:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseDialogCommand, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MainWindow}}}"
```

Now the problem here is that for some unknown reason, the Command to close the dialog won't fire (which is the MainViewModel). Accessing the MainViewModel is working from UserControl to UserControl but now that it's been opened from the Dialog, I can't seem to fire the ActionCommand inside the MainViewModel that closes the Dialog using the same code from the above XAML.

I've been stuck here for days. I hope someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I just need to create a DialogService Class for all of this. I got it all working flawlessly in MVVM.